# Transform causes text smoothing

Tags: css

I have a text which has

```
transform: rotate(-45deg) scale(1.6);
```

and his parent element block, which has

```
transform: rotate(45deg) translateX(30%)
```

And the text is smoothing. I've tried so far:

```
font-smoothing: antialiased;
-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
-moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
font-variant-ligatures: none;
-webkit-font-variant-ligatures: none;
text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
transform: perspective(1px) translateZ(0) translate3d(0, 0, 0);
```

How can I fix smoothing?

Comment: put a complete code with HTML/CSS and not only CSS property

Comment: This may be a browser/OS-specific issue. In which browser/OS the problem occurs?

Answer (score 0):

As you will see, there is no smoothed text for this simple example.

As @Temani Afif said in comments, put a snippet that reproduce your issue if you want more accurate responses.

```css
div {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid gray;
}

div:first-child {
  top: 150px;
}

p.rotate {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  transform: rotate(45deg) translateX(30%);
}

p.rotate span {
  display: block;
  transform: rotate(-45deg) scale(1.6);
  border: 1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p class=rotate>
    <span>TOTO</span>
  </p>
</div>

<div>
  <p>
    <span>TOTO</span>
  </p>
</div>
```